# Adnroid 'startForegroundService() did not then call Service.startForeground()' error

Tags: android

I tried a lot to solve the startForegroundService() did not then call Service.startForeground() error problem but I couldn't solve it

I still get the error startForegroundService() did not then call Service.startForeground() sometimes

Is there any way to definitely get rid of this problem?

I haven't found that issue on any device I have, but users using the app occasionally get that error

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),AlarmService.class);
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
{
    getContext().startForegroundService(intent);
}
else
{
    getContext().startService(intent);
}
```

```
public class AlarmService extends Service
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = null;
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        {
            String channelId = "clip_id";
            String channelName = "alarm";
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId,channelName,NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

            channel.setShowBadge(false);

            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);

            mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(),channelId);
        }
        else {
            mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), "alarm");
        }

        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.noti_icon)
                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.noti_title))
                .setContentText(getString(R.string.noti_content))
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        startForeground(1, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```